# Angular submit proceed just 1st time v2 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-submit

im new in Angular and I'm trying to make site with list of books (with properties a,b,c,d) and where u can add new book. 1st time when i submit everythik goes fine and 2nd time i get this error v2.newBook is not a function. Does anyone knows why its working 1st time and 2nd time not? Thx

```
`https://plnkr.co/edit/OtfLPuQFptfgUxuo0pXJ`
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  You will have a much higher chance of receiving an answer to your question if you provide a bit of additional information.  In particular, it is important to provide the relevant code to your problem *in the question body*.  Links to other websites alone don't provide context to others in the future, and hiding links inside the code blocks makes the link not clickable.  Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, #1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://plnkr.co/edit/3wwbDfTjcVQKx0VmsDFn?p=preview

---

Here is a working plnkr. You have both your function and object as newBook which is causing the problem.

---

```
$scope.newBook1 = function(book) {
    book.id = $scope.books.length;
    $scope.books.push(book);
    resetForm();
  }
```

---

HTML :

```
    <form class="form-group" ng-show="newBookForm" ng-submit="newBook1(newBook)" novalidate>
```

---

Answer (score 2):

It's because you use the same name for the function to call and for the book model itself. After initiation only the `$scope.newBook` `function` exists, but later on you overwrite that with your book model. Just simply rename either the function or the model.

Answer (score 1):

in your code function `resetForm()` convert `$scope.newBook` function to object

```
 $scope.newBook = function(book) {
    book.id = $scope.books.length;
    $scope.books.push(book);
    resetForm();
  }

  function resetForm() {
    $scope.newBook = { //here you defined newBook again as object
      d: '',
      b: '',
      c: '',
      d: ''
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have made a tiny mistake in your code, actually you have reset d object twice and left resetting a.
function resetForm() {
    $scope.newBook = {
      d: '',
      b: '',
      c: '',
      d: ''
    }
  }

just change d:'' to a:'' and it will run.

Thanks